# How to create custom vim command with shell command

Tags: shell, vim, command

I often create new files with the name of today's date. So, I would like to make this a command that calls the shell `date` command. The `date` command I use is:

```bash
date +%Y-%m-%d-%B%d).md
```

I tried to call this same shell command from within Vim with this custom command in my `.vimrc`:

```
command Post e !date +%Y-%m-%d-%B%d.md
```

But that doesn't work because `%` means the current filename in Vim and the desired filename isn't created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in `:help strftime()` function instead of the `date` command. This makes the command a little bit more portable and, since the function is evaluated before `:edit` is executed, you don't get the unwanted side-effects of `:help cmdline-special`.

```
:command! Post execute 'edit ' .. strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%B%d') .. '.md'
```

Comment: This is great! I'm not much of a vim-scripter so I wasn't familiar with the builtin strftime. Thanks for opening my eyes to this.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that @romainl idea of using builtin functions is a better approach than just delegating in the shell. For the sake of displaying how would it be to open (:edit) a file name resulting of a shell command would be something like this:

```
:command! Post execute 'let file=system("date +\\%Y-\\%m-\\%d-\\%B\\%d.md") | normal! :e ' .. file .. '^M'
```

- You need to quote the '%' with double \.
- You need to invoke the shell command before calling the `:edit` command,
  if you do something like: `execute "normal! :e !date +%Y-%m-%d-%B%d.md"`
  the date command will not be evaluate but just verboten pasted to `:edit`.

Comment: Good point, but there was no need to call `system` and double escaping. This is enough: `command! -buffer Post execute '.!date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%B\%d\).md'`